# ScheduledExecutorService multiple threads in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, executor

I'm interested in using `ScheduledExecutorService` to spawn multiple threads for tasks if task before did not yet finish. For example I need to process a file every 0.5s. First task starts processing file, after 0.5s if first thread is not finished second thread is spawned and starts processing second file and so on. This can be done with something like this:

```java
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4)
    while (!executor.isShutdown()) {  
        executor.execute(task);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // handle
        }
    }
```

Now my question: Why I can't do it with `executor.scheduleAtFixedRate`?

What I get is if the first task takes longer, the second task is started as soon as first finished, but no new thread is started even if executor has pool of threads. `executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay` is clear - it executes tasks with same time span between them and it doesn't matter how long it takes to complete the task. So probably I misunderstood `ScheduledExecutorService` purpose.

Maybe I should look at another kind of executor? Or just use code which I posted here? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 13):

I've solved the problem by launching a nested anonymous runnable in each scheduled execution:

```
final ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(POOL_SIZE);

final Runnable command = new SlowRunnable();

service.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        service.execute(command);
      }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

With this example there will be 1 thread executing at every interval a fast instruction, so it will be surely be finished when the next interval is expired. The remaining POOL_SIZE-1 threads will be executing the SlowRunnable's run() in parallel, which may take longer time than the duration of the single interval.

Please note that while I like this solution as it minimize the code and reuse the same ScheduledExecutorService, it must be sized correctly and may not be usable in every context: if the SlowRunnable is so slow that up to POOL_SIZE jobs get executed together, there will be no threads to run the the scheduled task in time.

Also, if you set the interval at 1 TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS it will probably became too slow also the execution of the main runnable.

Answer (score -1):

One of the [scheduleAtFixedRate](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) methods is what you're looking for. It starts a task in a thread from the pool at the given interval, even if previous tasks haven't finished. If you're running out of threads to do the processing, adjust the pool size constraints as detailed in the [ThreadPoolExecutor docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Comment: You linked to scheduleAtFixedRate method, and javadoc states: "If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute." Thats exactly how it works when i tried... scheduleWithFixedDelay does not fit either, since it starts counting for delay after first task ends. And it does not matter how big thread pool is. This is strange for me that ScheduledExecutorService does not have method for parallel execution, or maybe i miss or misunderstand something, thats why Im asking :)

Comment: Ohh, I see. I missed that. I guess the question would be, "Are they really the same task if you want to execute two of them at once?" If you're convinced they are, then I think java.util.concurrent might not support that particular usage.

Comment: The answer is wrong! Please edit it and add comment for readers